Problems deploying (brandingset) via VS Code
I have this package.xml:
    <types>
        <members>LEXTHEMINGTR2C2</members>
        <name>BrandingSet</name>
    </types>
    ...
    <types>
        <members>R2C2</members>
        <name>LightningExperienceTheme</name>
    </types>

In the file structure I do have the files
LEXTHEMINGR2C2.brandingSet-meta.xml
R2C2.lightningExperienceTheme-meta.xml
Also, in the LightningExperience.settings-meta.xml file I have this:
<activeThemeName>R2C2</activeThemeName>

So I guess I'm doing alright with the sources.
But, when deploying (deploy source in manifest to org) to a destination org, I get these two errors:

API: In field: defaultBrandingSet - no BrandingSet named LEXTHEMINGR2C2 found
Lightning Experience (Settings) In field: developerName - no LightningExperienceTheme named R2C2 found

Is there anything I'm missing here?
FILE: LEXTHEMINGR2C2.brandingSet-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BrandingSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>BRAND_COLOR</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>#2E5497</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>PAGE_BACKGROUND_COLOR</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>#FFFFFF</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>HEADER_BACKGROUND_COLOR</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>#FFFFFF</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>BRAND_IMAGE</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>/file-asset/Logo600x120?v=1</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>BANNER_IMAGE</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>/file-asset/fondoapp1800x3601?v=1</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>GROUPS_BANNER_IMAGE</propertyName>
        <propertyValue></propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>GROUP_IMAGE</propertyName>
        <propertyValue></propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>PROFILE_BANNER_IMAGE</propertyName>
        <propertyValue></propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>USER_IMAGE</propertyName>
        <propertyValue></propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>LINK_AS_BACKGROUND</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>true</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <brandingSetProperty>
        <propertyName>OVERRIDE_LOADING_PAGE</propertyName>
        <propertyValue>false</propertyValue>
    </brandingSetProperty>
    <masterLabel>R2C2</masterLabel>
</BrandingSet>

FILE: R2C2.lightningExperienceTheme-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningExperienceTheme xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <defaultBrandingSet>LEXTHEMINGR2C2</defaultBrandingSet>
    <description>Tema y marca de R2C2</description>
    <masterLabel>R2C2</masterLabel>
    <shouldOverrideLoadingImage>false</shouldOverrideLoadingImage>
</LightningExperienceTheme>


use [edit] and show the XML inside the BrandingSet and LightningExperienceTheme

Done. I added the content of the files!

I made it!
As it turns out (in a trial-and-error exercise), the prefix "LEXTHEMING" is useless. I removed any reference to the prefix.
In the package.xml I just let the branding set name as it was:
<types>
    <members>R2C2</members>
    <name>BrandingSet</name>
</types>

The file name is R2C2.brandingSet-meta.xml (as it should be).
And it worked.

exploding the XML is a good trick to use when you get these odd deployment errors

I'm sorry I don't really understand what is "exploding the XML"...

i meant to compliment you on showing all of the XML for the failing component to help understand what the root cause issue could be
